# Why am I getting 'undefined is not a function' for this destructuring assignment code?

Tags: javascript, express, destructuring

Say I have this request coming into an API route:

```
/api/things?p=2&t=25&some_id=67&another_id=89
```

Can I use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the parameters into local variables? I've tried this:

```
const [p, t, ...otherParams] = request.query;
```

...but I get "undefined is not a function" at runtime, which is an odd error that I can't debug. What I'd really love is to use destructuring with defaults. In my flawed syntax, that would be something like:

```
const [p = 1, t = 25, ...otherParams] = request.query;
```

Is this possible? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try using `{}` instead of `[]`

Comment: @Brandon Oh FFS, yep, that's it. Works great with `{}`. If you think it will help others, please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Otherwise, if you don't, I'll delete my question shortly. Thank you!

Comment: I'll post an answer to the question "why am I getting 'undefined is not a function' for this destructuring code?"  Maybe you can edit the question to match :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value you are destructuring is an object, not an array.  Therefore you need to use the object destructuring syntax.  If you use the wrong flavor you get the not very helpful "undefined is not a function" error.

```
const {p = 1, t = 25, ...otherParams} = request.query
```

I struggled with this very same error last Friday.